# How to get value of radio button with dynamically generated name

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have a whole bunch of radio buttons with dynamically generated names like below:

```
        <input type="radio" id="Red<?php echo $wineID; ?>" name="category<?php echo $wineID; ?>" value="Red" <?php if ($category == "Red") { ?>checked="true"<?php } ?>>
          <label for="Red<?php echo $wineID; ?>">Red</label>

        <input type="radio" id="White<?php echo $wineID; ?>" name="category<?php echo $wineID; ?>" value="White" <?php if ($category == "White") { ?>checked="true"<?php } ?>>
          <label for="White<?php echo $wineID; ?>">White</label>

        <input type="radio" id="Sparkling<?php echo $wineID; ?>" name="category<?php echo $wineID; ?>" value="Sparkling" <?php if ($category == "Sparkling") { ?>checked="true"<?php } ?>>
          <label for="Sparkling<?php echo $wineID; ?>">Sparkling</label>
```

I need to get the selected value and add it into my dataString for an ajax call to update my database. How can this be done using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked')
```

as in:

```
alert( $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute selector to get the element

```
$('input[name="category<?php echo $wineID; ?>:selected"')
```

However this uses a PHP inline script, so it will only work if rendered at the page load.

Or easiest would be:

```
console.log($(":radio:selected").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the name attribute from an onchange event (using jQuery)

```
// Onload handler
$(function() {
    // Get all radio buttons and add an onchange event
    $("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(){
        // Output a message in the console which shows the name and state
        console.log($(this).attr("name"), $(this).is(":checked"));

    // Trigger the onchange event for any checked radio buttons after the onload event has fired
    }).filter(":checked").trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a parent div with `id="anything"`

now using jquery selector `$('#anything input[type="radio"]:checked').val()`

you can achieve that